# Copying/Pasting a block of lines in vi editor

Tags: vi

I have a strange problem when copying/pasting a group of lines within vi. For example, let us say we have a group of lines as follows:

```
AAAAAAAA   AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBB  BBBBB   BBBBBBBBBB
CCCCC    CCC  CCCCCCCC  CCCC
```

If I copy these lines and paste it, the lines are pasted like this

```
AAAAA AAAAAAAAAA
            BBBBBBBB    BBBBBB  BBBBBBBBBBB
                      CCCCC  CCC  CCCCCCCC  CCCC
```

The value of TERM environment variable is `vt320`. I don't know if this has an effect. But it worked before. I open a session using putty. Any clues?

Comment: I'm not sure if the formatting isn't how you intended but I don't see the difference you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

This is presumably because of the `paste` option. From [`:h paste`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'paste'):

```
                        *'paste'* *'nopaste'*
'paste'         boolean (default off)
            global
            {not in Vi}
    Put Vim in Paste mode.  This is useful if you want to cut or copy
    some text from one window and paste it in Vim.  This will avoid
    unexpected effects.
    Setting this option is useful when using Vim in a terminal, where Vim
    cannot distinguish between typed text and pasted text.  In the GUI, Vim
    knows about pasting and will mostly do the right thing without 'paste'
    being set.  The same is true for a terminal where Vim handles the
    mouse clicks itself.
```

I'd assume this is happening because you have some indent settings, so as you paste, vim assumes you're typing instead of pasting, and adds the necessary indents automatically. If you `:set paste`, it will stop doing this.

Of course, one other solution is to use gvim instead of a terminal. It's up to you whether this option worth it to you.